# WebStorm live edit doesn't work

Tags: webstorm

I have installed `WebStorm 5.0.4` + `JetBrains Chrome Extension 0.3.11`, checked `View -> Live Edit`. Now I'm openning `index.html`, right click, `Open in browser`. File is openned by Chrome (`file:///D:/Dropbox/index.html`) but live edit doesn't work

`Chrome 23.0.1271.64 m`, `Windows 7`. Option `View -> Reload in Browser` is not active, `DevTools` is not active

**Added**
I have opened background page of chrome extension and found a lot of errors
`Unexpected response code: 400 chrome-extension://omlgoegcnmiikfiapaelkaichppahfkm:1`

May be this is the reason of problem?

Comment: Does extension has been allowed to access `file:///` protocol ?

Comment: I think yes. Is it 'Allow open files by links'? It's checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might try this fix it worked for me but I'm on XP:

Download https://dl.dropbox.com/u/43511007/webide.jar and copy to WebStorm-install-dir/lib (replace existing file).

from :

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/439550?tstart=0

Comment: File no longer available... :-(  was this allegedly fixed?

Answer (score 4):

Dude, don't do that if you have the latest version. Just:

1. close Chrome
2. close webstorm
3. start webstorm
4. start chrome

And click view->reload in browser, and make sure check view->live editing

Comment: Worked! In my case webstorm was confused because pydef connected to the plugin before and after closing pydef webstorm still wasn't able to reconnect. A restart of chrome and webstorm did the trick.

Comment: Just restart web storm and it will work like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Get Live Edit worked!

I'm using Webstorm on Windows, if you're using other IDE, please fit it yourself.

Edit file `<WebStorm installed dir>/bin/WebStorm.exe.vmoptions`.

For Mac OS, edit file `/Applications/<WebStorm.app>/bin/idea.vmoptions`.

simply add this single line:

`-Drpc.port=53342`

Then change the port number in plugin option page to the above port.

Live Edit should work now.

Answer (score -1):

You get it from the Chrome store - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji